# Getting all CNGroups from CNContactStore

Tags: ios, ios9, contacts, cncontact

It seems that there is no way to get the groups from a CNContactStore. The CNContactStore uses a predicate that requires the group identifier to get the group. CNContact does not have any way to find out what group it is in (that I can find).

Is there something I am missing in the documentation? It would really help to be able to see all the available groups in a contact store, and I find it difficult to believe that it isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something I am missing in the documentation

Yes. What you are missing in the documentation is the documentation, which tells you the answer:

Pass a `nil` predicate to fetch all groups.

Comment: Look at that, it's spelled out right there in the docs. Feeling dumb. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer to answer the question you actually asked.